# How can I correct the following code concerning matching bit patterns?

Tags: c, function, bit

I have been tasked to write a function called `bitpatSearch()` which looks for a specified bit pattern inside an `unsigned int`. The function should take 3 arguments: `bitpatSearch(source, pattern, n)`. It should search the integer `source`for the rightmost `n`bits of `pattern` and output the number of bits where the pattern begins (assume 0 to 31st bit ordering for a 32 bit integer) if there is a match and `-1` if there is no match.

Although the exercise recommended to search from the leftmost bit, my code searches from the rightmost one, as I thought it would be easier (as I could AND values with `1`.) However, something is wrong, and I suspect that the arithmetic behind the `return` statement might be an issue, but can't quite figure it out.

The program seems to always get the position wrong, but always tells me correctly whether there is a match.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bitpatSearch(unsigned int source, unsigned int pattern, int n){

unsigned int count, x, sourceCopy;

for(count = 0; count <= 32; ++count){ //loop for all possible shifts for a 32 bit integer

   x = 0; 

   sourceCopy = source >> count;

   while(((sourceCopy & 1) == (pattern & 1)) && (x != n)){

      sourceCopy >>= 1;

      pattern >>= 1;

      ++x;

      }

   if(x == n) //then there is a match

   return 32 - (count + n); // I think the problem is here, with basic arithmetic

}

return -1;

}
```

Comment: Can you please give some example input, expected result and actual result?

Comment: @kaylum For instance: bitpatSearch(243, 9, 4) outputs a match (which is correct), but states that its the 20th bit, at which the pattern begins. This is not the case, as the pattern begins on the 27th bit.

Comment: Try count-n+1 to get the proper result at least in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You partially destroy `pattern` in the inner while loop by shifting it as bits are matched. So if you get a partial match, then `pattern` will no longer hold the correct value for subsequent searches. An example that your code gets wrong is `bitpatSearch(0xf0f, 0xff, 8)`. You code finds a match at position 12, but there is no match anywhere.

I'd write the code like this:

```
#include <limits.h>

#define INT_BITS (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned))

int bitpatSearch(unsigned int source, unsigned int pattern, int n){
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n > INT_BITS) return -1;
    if (n == INT_BITS) return source == pattern ? 0 : -1;
    pattern &= (1u << n) - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= INT_BITS - n; i++) {
        if (((source >> i) & ((1u << n) - 1)) == pattern) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Unlike your code, this tries to match the entirety of `pattern` at a given shift value in `source` at a single go, and is portable as it doesn't assume that `int` is a particular size.

The code works hard to avoid undefined behavior; specifically avoiding shifts by INT_BITS or more. For example, the case `if (n == INT_BITS) return source == pattern ? 0 : -1;` is necessary to avoid an illegal shift when constructing the mask `(1u << n) - 1`.

Here's some simple unit tests for the code. Some of the test cases assume a 32 bit int because I was too lazy to make them portable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct {
        unsigned source, pattern;
        int n;
        int want;
    } test_cases[] = {
        { 0x0000000fu, 0xf, 4, 0 },
        { 0x0000000fu, 0xf, 2, 0 },
        { 0xf0000000u, 0xf, 4, 28 },
        { 0xf0000000u, 0xf, 2, 28 },
        { 0x01000000u, 0x1, 4, 24 },
        { 0x80000000u, 0x1, 1, 31 },
        { 1u << (INT_BITS - 1), 0x1, 2, -1 },
        { 0xffffffffu, 0x6, 3, -1 },
        { 0x777u, 0x77, 12, 4 },
        { 0x1234abcdu, 0x1234abcdu, 32, 0 },
        { 0x1234abcdu, 0x1234abcdu, 33, -1 },
        { 0x1234abcdu, 0x42u, 0, 0 },
        { 0xf0f, 0xff, 8, -1},
    };

    int failed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(test_cases) / sizeof(test_cases[0]); i++) {
        unsigned source = test_cases[i].source;
        unsigned pattern = test_cases[i].pattern;
        int n = test_cases[i].n;
        int want = test_cases[i].want;
        int got = bitpatSearch(source, pattern, n);
        if (got != want) {
            printf("bitpatSearch(0x%x, 0x%x, %d) = %d, want %d\n", source, pattern, n, got, want);
            failed = 1;
        }
    }
    return failed ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a copy of `pattern` because every time you enter the while loop you are changing the value of `pattern`. So the next time you enter the while loop you will be comparing with wrong pattern.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int bitpatSearch(unsigned int source, unsigned int pattern, int n){

unsigned int count, x, sourceCopy,patternCopy;

for(count = 0; count <= 32; ++count){ //loop for all possible shifts for a 32 bit integer

   x = 0;

   sourceCopy = source >> count;
   patternCopy=pattern;

   while(((sourceCopy & 1) == (patternCopy & 1)) && (x < n)){


      sourceCopy >>= 1;

      patternCopy >>= 1;

      ++x;
      }

   if(x == n) //then there is a match

   return 32 - (count + n); // I think the problem is here, with basic arithmetic

}

return -1;

}
int main()
{
    printf("%d",bitpatSearch(243,9,4));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just got that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot shift a 32 bit `unsigned int` by 32, it is not defined.  Change the loop to stop before 32:

```
for (count = 0; count < 32; ++count)
```

Or better, make it loop over the size of the type for your system, which might be different than 32:

```
#include <limits.h>

...

for (count = 0; count < sizeof(source) * CHAR_BIT; ++count)
```

Regarding your algorithm, if you are supposed to search from the most significant bit, do that!  Otherwise, you might not find the expected position if the pattern is present more than once.

Note that it is very confusing to talk about bit numbers without a precise definition of the numbering system: is bit `0` the leftmost (most significant) or the rightmost (least significant) bit?  In C, it is common to number bits from the least significant to the most significant, as this is consistent with the shift operator (bit `n` has the value `1U << n`), but some people are used to number bits from left to right, exactly the opposite convention.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that bit numbering is usually from right to left, where the rightmost bit is bit 0.

Your code is very complicated. Nested loops are not necessary. Here is an easy solution for your problem (pattern search is from right to left):

(EDIT: Code now includes improvements as suggested by Paul Hankin and underscore_d.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define NO_MATCH -1
#define ARGUMENT_ERROR -2

#define DEBUG

int bitpatSearch(unsigned int source, unsigned int pattern, unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int mask;
    unsigned int tmp;
    int i;

    /********************************************************************
     * Three trivial cases:
     * 
     * (a) If n = 0, then every pattern is a match; so return 0
     *     (match at position 0).
     * (b) If n = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(source), then there is a match at
     *     position 0 if source equals pattern and no match otherwise.
     * (c) If n > CHAR_BIT * sizeof(source), it makes no sence to test
     *     for matching patterns, because we don't know the
     *     n - CHAR_BIT * sizeof(source) most significant bits.
     *******************************************************************/
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == CHAR_BIT * sizeof(source)) {
        if (source == pattern) {
            return 0;
        }
        return NO_MATCH;
    }
    if (n > CHAR_BIT * sizeof(source)) {
        return ARGUMENT_ERROR;
    }

    mask = ~((~0u) << n);
    pattern &= mask;

    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("mask    = 0x%08x\n", mask);
    printf("pattern = 0x%08x\n", pattern);
    #endif

    for (i = 0; i <= CHAR_BIT * sizeof(source) - n; i++) {
        tmp = (source >> i) & mask;
        #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("tmp     = 0x%08x at position %2i:\n", tmp, i);
        #endif
        if (tmp == pattern) {
            #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("Match at position %2i!\n", i);
            #endif
            return i;
        }
    }

    return NO_MATCH;
}

int main() {
    int result;

    /*
    dec 243 = bin 11110011
    dec   9 = bin    1001
                        ^ match at position 1
    */

    result = bitpatSearch(243, 9, 4);
    printf("Result = %i\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a few bugs here. If n >= 32, constructing the mask is undefined behavior -- the case n==32 is particularly important to get right, as it's a reasonable input. I think you've got an off-by-one error on your for loop which will prevent matching the pattern at the most significant end of `source`. A final very minor non-portability is that  `(~0) << n` is undefined behavior for n==31 if you're on a one's complement machine. Probably `(~0u) << n` is better to avoid worrying about the signed shifts at all. I include some unit tests in my solution that you can check your implementation with.

Comment: The idea of using `sizeof` is nice and potentially improves portability... but falls short as you then assume `CHAR_BIT` is 8, which might be true for 99.allthe9s% of users but makes the code inherently nonportable. The solution is to use `CHAR_BIT` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I was also considering comparing the values in their entirety, but couldn't figure out the simple stuff like the upper bound for i in your for loop.